# Is the zero element of a Banach space the same as the zero element of a space that it is continuously embedded within?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two Banach spaces and the embedding $ X \hookrightarrow Y $ is continuous.
Does $ Y $ has the same zero element as $ X $? For me it seems trivial but I don't have the right arguement in hand. This question emerged from some contradiction arguement I was trying to prove that involved some $ u \in X$ such that $   \left\|u  \right\|_X  = 1 $ but $   \left\|u  \right\|_Y = 0$ which would mean $ u = 0 $ in $Y$, hence $ \left\|u  \right\|_X  = 0 $ which is a contradiction. But I'm not sure how to justify that the zero element of $Y$ is the same as the zero element of $X$. We already know that since these are normed spaces, they are vector spaces. Is this enough and why? If $X$ was a subspace of $Y$ this is obvious but we do not know that.

**Note:** Our notion of a continuous embedding is as defined in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_embedding).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_embedding

Comment: Thanks! I've included the wikipedia link in the body of your question

Comment: Thank you for your edits.

Comment: Only the group structure with addition is sufficient. The space $X$ can be treated a subgroup of $Y.$ Hence the neutral elements under addition are identical. The continuity is not necessary.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you. That was my first thought. We would only have to show that $X$ is a subgroup of $Y$ which is trivial due to the fact that they are both vector spaces and we have a set inclusion between them. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: For the group , sub-group argument to work, addition in $X$ as a vector space must be same as addition in $Y$ as a vector space ! or atleast both these additions must be related.

Comment: @Balajisb Yes you're right. So a priori, we need to know if addition is defined in the same way, in both $X$ and $Y$ in order to deduce that one is a subgroup of the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By wiki link you posed, Assuming $||x||_Y = 0 \iff x = 0_Y$ and $||x||_X = 0 \iff x = 0_X$, by continuous embedding definition you posted in Wiki link, $||0_X||_Y \leq C ||0_X||_X = 0 \implies ||0_X||_Y  = 0 \implies 0_X = 0_Y$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is absolutely expository.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be proved with the idea of unicity of $0$. Since $X \subseteq Y$, for any $x \in X \subseteq Y$ we have $x + 0_X = x$, and I don't think this can hold for any other element of $Y$ other than $0_Y$. Maybe there can be one zero for each space if the operations of addition are defined differently, making $x_1 +_x x_2 \neq x_1 +_Y x_2$

Comment: Yes that's what I thought and I needed some detail on why this cannot hold for any other element. Intuitively speaking, I see it exactly as you answered above.